# Plotly: How to fix that dendrogram leaves big blank space?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am working on this function that creates a dendrogram. The dataframe can be quite big, so I would like to scale the size of the figure according to its content. But for larger figures the y-ticks are not equally distributed leaving this ugly big empty space in the end.

```
df = pd.DataFrame( np.random.random(size=(1000, 1000)) )

def plotly_dendrogram(df: pd.DataFrame(), labels=None, 
                      orientation='left', color_threshold=0,
                      height=None, width=None, max_label_lenght=30):
    if labels is None:
        labels = df.index
        
    if height is None:
        height = max(300, 10*len(df))
    fig = ff.create_dendrogram(df, color_threshold=color_threshold, 
                               labels=labels, orientation=orientation)
    fig.update_layout(width=width, height=height, font_family="Monospace")
    fig.update_layout(xaxis_showgrid=True, yaxis_showgrid=True)
    fig.update_yaxes(automargin=True)
    fig.update_xaxes(automargin=True)
    return fig

plotly_dendrogram(df)
```

Is there a way to make plotly distribute the ticks equally over the available space?

[image: enter code here]

Comment: How did my suggestion work out for you?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a [well known issue](https://community.plotly.com/t/dendrogram-does-not-fully-fill-the-container/32728) that apparently exists for even the latest plotly versions. For larger datasets, the background seems to get increasingly misaligned with the dendrogram itself. But as it turns out, this can be easily fixed by retrieving the global minimum and maximum for all traces and setting the y-axis range accordingly like this:

```
y_max = []
y_min = []
for t in fig['data']:
    y_max.append(t['y'].max())
    y_min.append(t['y'].min())

rngs = [min(y_min), max(y_max)]
fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(range=[rngs[0]-5, rngs[1]]))
fig.show()
```

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data sample
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame( np.random.random(size=(500, 500)))
df.index = df.index.map(str)

def plotly_dendrogram(df: pd.DataFrame(), labels=None, 
                      orientation='left', color_threshold=0,
                      height=None, width=None, max_label_lenght=30):
    if labels is None:
        labels = df.index
    
    if max_label_lenght is not None:
        labels = [i[:max_label_lenght] for i in labels]
        
    if height is None:
        height = max(300, 10*len(df))
    fig = ff.create_dendrogram(df, color_threshold=color_threshold, 
                               labels=labels, orientation=orientation)
    fig.update_layout(width=width, height=height, font_family="Monospace")
    fig.update_layout(xaxis_showgrid=True, yaxis_showgrid=True)
    fig.update_yaxes(automargin=True)
    fig.update_xaxes(automargin=True)
    return fig

fig = plotly_dendrogram(df)

y_max = []
y_min = []
for t in fig['data']:
    y_max.append(t['y'].max())
    y_min.append(t['y'].min())

fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(range=[min(y_min)-5, max(y_max)]))
fig.show()
```